# How to change animator states from a key press in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, animator

I am working on a small beat-em-up game as a summer project. I am stuck trying to change the sprite animation when a key is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Jotaro Idle"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                anim.SetTrigger("WalkRightfromIdle");
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                anim.SetTrigger("WalkLeftFromIdle");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my animator window (each transition is controlled by a trigger) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFbC.jpg

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of Triggers here you should rather use **Bools** like e.g. `isWalkingLeft` and `isWalkingRight` and do something like `if isWalkingLeft` => go to Walking Left state, `if isWalkingRight` => go to Walking Right state, if none of both => go to idle state

Answer (score -1):

Try using `anim.Play(...)` instead of `anim.SetTrigger(...)`.

Comment: I have. It does not seem to work in that regard either.

Comment: Is your idle animation even playing? Have you attached script & animator to the gameobject?

Comment: My idle animation does play when I play the preview. I have the animator attached to my sprite object, but I am not sure how to attach the script.

Comment: Drag your script with this code to the main camera panel, it will get automatically attached. Or you can add it as any physics available, you just have to select scripts there and then your script. Also, you may have to attach your script to gameobject which's animation you are changing, so it makes sure that only that object's animator state is changed.

Comment: Attaching the script to my Sprite Object does not fix the issue. I tested it with both SetTrigger and Play. I am also now wondering if I need the gameObject lead for the GetComponent. Is that necessary?